# Passing a pointer to class into unmanaged c++ code from C#

Tags: c#, c++, marshalling, unmanaged

I have a c++ exported function in dll:

```
int MyMethod(ulong pid, MyStruct* struct);
```

MyStruct is described as class:

```
class MyStruct
{
public:
uchar   nVersion;
uchar   nModuleType;
uchar   nMachine64;
uchar   nReserved;
ulong  data1;
ulong  data2;
ulong  data3;
};
```

I'm trying to import this function to my C# code like this:

```
[DllImport("mydll.dll", EntryPoint = "#24")]
private static extern int _MyMethod(long pid, ref MyStruct struct);
```

Class in C#:

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayoutAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.LayoutKind.Sequential)]
stuct MyStruct
{
    public byte nVersion;
    public byte nModuleType;
    public byte nMachine64;
    public byte nReserved;
    public ulong data1;
    public ulong data2;
    public ulong data3;
}
```

And i'm getting `System.AccessViolationException`:

```
MyStruct struct = new MyStruct();
_MyMethod(4728, ref struct);
```

What's wrong?

UPDATE:
`System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(struct)` returns 32. Why? I thought it should be 4 * 1 + 8 * 3 = 28

Comment: it has nothing to do with the "unsafe" keyword, its just a standard marshal problem ...

Comment: @user287107 You are correct, I took the question out of context of the answer.

Comment: By the way, I used to write the same code for Delphi to use c++ dll - and it worked. So there can't be problem in dll.

Comment: The size is different because of padding. The compiler will increase the struct size to a convenient number.

Comment: Does c++ do the same? I thought maybe this is the problem

Comment: As others have said, change ulong at one end or the other so that they're both the same size.  Then check sizeof() at both ends and make sure they're the same - if they're not then you'll need to adjust the packing of the structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C# we have `class`es and `struct`s. All `class` types are reference but `struct` types are value types. This means when you have something like `class MyStruct` and you write `MyStruct s` it is actually something like a pointer to base class, and when you pass it by reference you actually pass address of that pointer, so it has nothing to do with C++ that expect a pointer to main `struct`. According to this solution to your problem is to convert `class` to `struct`.

`long` and `ulong` in C# are 64 bit types while they are 32 bit in C++(MSVC at least), so when you declare your function such that its first parameter is `long` you send extra 32 bit value that may override next parameter and cause it to be invalid:

```
Stack:
    32 bit: [first 32 bit of the first parameter]
    32 bit: [second 32 bit of the first parameter]
    32 bit: [address of your structure]
```

So when function called it will take an invalid parameter as address of struct. so just change your function definition to:

```
[DllImport("mydll.dll", EntryPoint = "#24")]
private static extern int _MyMethod(int pid, ref MyStruct struct);
```

An your struct to:

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayoutAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.LayoutKind.Sequential)]
stuct MyStruct
{
    public byte nVersion;
    public byte nModuleType;
    public byte nMachine64;
    public byte nReserved;
    public uint data1;
    public uint data2;
    public uint data3;
}
```

may be source of your error is in first parameter of the function, because function expect a 32 bit value and you provide a 64 bit one and actually you provide 2, 32 bit value to the function that cause the function

Comment: @DenisKildishev One extra note `ulong` in C# is UInt64 in CLR but `ulong` in C++ is `UInt32` in CLR or `uint` in C#, of course this is not source of `AccessViolationException` in your code

Comment: thank you! Did't know that. long in _MyMethod's argument was of course critical

Answer (score 1):

SizeOf() returns 32 because of the alignment requirements for ulong, an 8 byte value type.  The default value for StructLayoutAttribute.Pack is 8, same as the default packing used in native code.  So data1 gets aligned to offset 8 and there's a 4 byte gap between nReserved and data1.  So 4 x 1 + 4 + 3 x 8 = 32.

You probably got that gap because in native C++ code compiled with the MSVC compiler, an ulong is 4 bytes.  Same as uint in C#.  So fix the structure declaration, replace ulong with uint.

Next problem, the cause of the AV, is that you declared the structure as a class in C#.  Which is a reference type which always gets passed by reference.  Your current declaration is equivalent to MyStruct** in C++ code.  Either remove the *ref* in the declaration or declare it as a struct instead of a class.